# Rails: Dynamic Select with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to create a dynamic SQL select statement to get the city, state combination from a table called `Metros` with the least distance from a set of passed in GPS coordinates. Note the set of passed in GPS coordinates are variables that will pull from a list. In order to calculate the distance I need to be able to pass in a latitude and longitude, and using the the haversine formula, calculate the distance between the present row and all 291 cities in the table `Metros`, then select the minimum City,state.

In rails the issue I am running into is how to properly create the select statement with the `Metros` table to allow for passing in the variable GPS coordinates but also using Active Record instead of conventional SQL.

At present, this is how far I have gotten:

```
    Metros.select(
        "major_city
        , major_state
        ," haversine(row[latitude], row[longitude], lat2, long2)" as 'distance'")
           .group("major_city,major_state").limit(1).order('distance')
```

`row[latitude], row[longitude]` are the passed in variable latitude and longitude (the present row I am comparing all 291 cities/states GPS coordinates in the `Metros` table and need to select the one with the least distance outputted by the Haversine function). As for `lat2, long2`, they need to refer to the latitude and longitude columns in the `Metros` table.

In building this query I am unaware of how to input the Haversine function as well as pull those records from the database with Active Record and calculate.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement haversine as a SQL function and then call in ActiveRecord like so:

```
Metros.select("major_city, major_state, haversine(?, ?, lat, long) as 'distance'", lat, long).
  group("major_city,major_state").
  limit(1).
  order('distance')
```